# Resize objects on resizing toplevel window in tcl/tk

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a TCL-TK complex GUI, with nested level of canvas and frames having text/como-box, list, tablelist etc. on a toplevel tk window.

All have been arranged using placed geometry manager.
Is their any way to resize the objects relatively to the toplevel window.

For the time being, I have added a scrollbar on the main canvas where all frames are placed, which becomes active on resizing the GUI. But that too hides in resizing under the objects inside the frame.

Tell some way to get out.

Comment: Use an other geometry manager, like grid. With place you have to resize all objects yourself.

Comment: you say your GUI is "TCL-TK" yet you include the tkinter tag. Why the tkinter tag?

Comment: Since TKinter is also based on Tcl-Tk,  a larger audience can suggest on the post.

Answer (score 4):

The `place` geometry manager is more difficult to use well than the other ones; it mostly behaves in a way that's quite a bit more primitive (unless you can use the relative placement and relative sizing of `place` to do what you want directly) and it doesn't do outward geometry propagation at all.

But the technique that you're probably looking for is to bind to outer widget's `<Configure>` event (be careful if that's a toplevel; toplevel bindings get all the events for all the widgets inside them too) which will be sent to you whenever the widget has its height or width changed. It's an ideal moment for either recalculating what you want the inside to do, or scheduling that recalculation to happen in an idle event (with `after idle`) so that you can bunch updates if necessary. Tk does that sort of thing a lot internally.

Try doing it the simple way to start out with. Here's a simple binding that lets you experiment with what notifications you actually get.

```
bind .outer <Configure> {
    puts "Window %w has changed width to %w and height to %h"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem is why I recommend that you should almost never use `place`. It is much more difficult to get proper resize behavior than the other geometry managers. In a couple decades of using tk, I've probably used `place` no more than five or six times.

That being said, `place` has options that allow you to specify widths and x/y coordinates relative to their master. For example, specifying `relwidth=1.0` will make the widget exactly the same width as its master window. Using `relheight=.5` makes the widget half as tall as the master window.

`place` is somewhat under-documented in the tkinter world (I mention because your question included the "tkinter" tag) but is well documented for tcl/tk. See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/place.htm for a list of options and a description of how they can be combined.